# flutter doctor command failed to retrieve the Dart SDK on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: flutter, dart

```
$flutter doctor
```

Running this command produces this output -

```
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine bdc9708d235e582483d299642ad8682826ebb90d...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:09 --:--:--     0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to storage.googleapis.com:443 

Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/bdc9708d235e582483d299642ad8682826ebb90d/dart-sdk-linux-x64.zip
If you're located in China, please see this page:
  https://flutter.dev/community/china
```

I am not from China, and it's my first trial on setting up flutter so I can't understand why this isn't working.
Also I have added flutter to system variables using -

```
$nano ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: check your internet connection

Comment: Check your internet and Try command [  flutter doctor -v  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later realized that `storage.googleapis` was blocked in Bangladesh that time, so just using a VPN worked.

Note: The site has been blocked yet again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue and found that the file in flutter/bin/internal called engine.version is where the "head" issue lies. I went to the flutter GitHub repo and found the same file then just replaced all the content of the file with what was in their repo.

Here's the [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/bin/internal/engine.version).

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
flutter doctor -v
```

as suggested by [nimey sara thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3716927/nimey-sara-thomas) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559067/flutter-doctor-command-failed-to-retrieve-the-dart-sdk-on-ubuntu-18-04/70284931#comment109871274_59559067) resolved the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

Verify if you have any antivirus activate. Personally, Kasperky blocked the installation, so, one of the solution can be deactivate your anti-virus

Answer (score 0):

i have also faced the similar issue when trying to install the dart sdk for the first time. In Bangladesh,the storage location is blocked(i dont know why) now. so, in that case you have two options either use a vpn or use the flutter storage location of china([china doc](https://flutter.dev/community/china)). using vpn is not a safer option for me so i opted for using storage location of china.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I just deleted the flutter folder I had on my machine and replaced it with a new one downloaded from the flutter website. That seemed to solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Kaspersky antivirus, it somehow was causing this problem, after turning it off, it started working again

Answer (score -1):

This is an openssl certificates error. This just means there is a problem trying to establish a secure connection to get the SDK, which points to an error in your local ssl config. So, try and fix your openssl installation.

Run the `openssl` command and see if there are any errors present. 
Try and link your certificate configuration file to the correct file if it is incorrect i.e if you get an error, failed to link to openssl.cnf file.

If all this does not work, try and do a fresh installation of openssl

```
sudo apt-get purge openssl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Comment: I do not recommend this. This did not fix the issue. And I had to do the following to fix the what the above advice broke: https://askubuntu.com/questions/420860/problem-with-certificates